# How to drag and drop to desktop in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment, nautilus

Answers on this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230884/cannot-move-files-from-and-to-desktop mention that the drag and drop to desktop does not work because in the experimental version of Nautlius. But as another answer points out, it does not seem to be possible to disable this.

This discussion about whether or not this is a feature or a bug: https://itsfoss.community/t/ubuntu-20-04-desktop-are-these-features-or-bugs/4610/13 did not seem to reach a consensus: some people claimed it was a bug and others said it was a feature.

Are we simply stuck with no drag and drop to desktop, or is there a work around? If not, will this eventually be possible, or is it an intended, permanent feature?

P.S. Please let us not turn this into a philosphical discussion whether this *should* be possible. I'm just wondering whether it is or will be.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Desktop folder from Nautlius, you can drag and drop to it from any other folder and it will show up on your Desktop.You can even drop onto it without opening it.
[image]

Comment: That's true, I was wondering specifically if it is possible to directly drag and drop onto the desktop, but yes it is not such a big deal since what you described is still possible. Was mostly asking out of curiosity

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's working. The only thing is that it's different from the drag and drop of windows.

Steps:

1. Select the files you want to drag.
2. Hold them with the left mouse button.
3. Press `Alt+Tab` and select the window in which you want to paste/move. (Keep pressing Tab until you reach your desired window)
4. Release `Alt+Tab` after reaching your destination window.
5. Release the left mouse button to drop your files.

And you are done!